# Thread Interruptded Exception, release semaphore resources

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have three threads and they need some resources to run (A,B,C) that I have implemented using Semaphores.

```
public void run(){
 while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted){
  try{
    A.acquire(2);
    B.acquire(2);
    //some-stuff
  }
  catch(InterruptedException ex){}
  finally{ 
     A.release(2); //PROBLEM
     B.release(2);
         }
  }
```

Problem: while running, the thread could be interrupted but, going in the `finally` method I don't know where I was during the interruption so I don't know if I have to release something or not.
I have tried a lot of different implementation, like using the method `(boolean) tryAcquire()`  but another problem comes up: if I get the resource A but not the B, then in the finally block I would release the A again etc.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `List` like this:

```
List<Semaphore> acquired = new ArrayList<>(2);
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) { 
  try{
    A.acquire(2);
    acquired.add(A);
    B.acquire(2);
    acquired.add(B);
    //some-stuff
  } catch(InterruptedException ex){}
  finally{ 
    for (Semaphore s : acquired) {
      s.release(2);
    }
    s.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the question turns around "atomic statement".
In your example, what if the interruption occours between A.acquire(2) and acquired.add(A) ? In the finally block 2 resources of A  wouldn't be released.

Comment: @alessandroAmedei if interruption occurs on `A.acquire(2)` then exception will be thrown and `finally` will be executed correctly (nothing was acquired, nothing to release). But if thread is interrupted between `acquire` and `acquired.add()` then no exception will be thrown and program will continue to execute and will add resource to the list

Comment: thank you!
Should this work?
`code public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

 boolean a = false;
 boolean b = false;
  try {
    Main.A.acquire(2);
    a = true;
    Main.B.acquire(2);
     b = true;

       buffer.setAB(value);
        value++;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            } finally {
               if (a) {
                 Main.A.release(2);
                }
                if (b) {
                  Main.B.release(2);
           }
         }

     }

   }`

Comment: @alessandroAmedei I think yes. You could also write unit tests for your code for both normal execution and `InterruptedException` case

Comment: I had to add  `code Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in the catch block if not it didn't work. Why?

Comment: When `InterruptedException` is thrown thread's interrupted status is cleared that is why you will have endless loop. So you'd better use a `boolean` flag in `while` condition and set it to false in `catch`. Check this link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523721/why-do-interruptedexceptions-clear-a-threads-interrupted-status

Comment: it didn't work because after the execution i checked the available resources in the semaphores and some of them were still busy. It was like that after the finally block some resources got acquire again.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `try` blocks:

```
try {
    A.acquire(2);
    try {
        B.acquire(2);
        try {
            // some stuff
        } finally {
            B.release(2);
        }
    } finally {
        A.release(2);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```