# Restoring Interruption flag status in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt-handling, interrupted-exception, interruption

Good Day!

I have been going through the Java Docs & some online resources on properly handling the `InterruptedException` due to bug reported by SonarQube. But not sure if I 100% understood if `Interruption flag` status always has to be restored whenever InterruptedException occurs inside a place where we can't throw exception for Ex: Runnable implementation.

Lets consider below replicated demo example code, where the main method is responsible for initiating some async method.The async method makes the Http GET request and processes(*by taking `runnable` as argument to the addListener method*) the response asynchronously.
[image]

**Note :** Now my query is Do I have to restore `Interruption status` flag at line#35. Why asking this is because,

1. This is my complete program, and nowhere am interrupting the task-thread which processes the actual GET request's response. But Interruption can happen due  to various factors which I understand. But **my requirement is very simple to always return back some default response no matter what exception I get**, even if it is `InterruptedException`. So, even without restoring the flag, my intention/requirement gets fulfilled i.e to complete the `CompletableFuture` with some default response.
2. And nowhere in my code I am going check for `Thread.interrupted()` OR `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` because I don't want to handle this as my requirement already got fulfilled by returning back default response.
3. After capturing the InterruptedException and completing the Future with some default response, am not processing anything further within this thread(Runnable).
4. After executing the InterruptedException  catch block, next my Main Thread will start executing with the received default response. And my Main Thread OR Parent Thread doesn't want to know OR doesn't care about if InterruptedException ever occurred-or-not. All it cares about is some valid response.

> Incase if I still want to restore the Interruption flag status, could
> someone please explain why to restore the same, and how can my code go
> wrong if I don't restore it?

. Because, as I said in above 4 points my requirement gets fulfilled even without restoring the flag.

Any enlightment/clarification on this topic for the above exact scenario is highly appreciatable.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523785/1527544

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss , Thanks for comment, but Yeah I went through SO post already and various such posts. But couldn't come to a conclusion. Hence I posted my question in SO.

Comment: @Antoniossss Could you please help me with above situation?

Comment: In your case I would just refactor to `catch(Excepion e) {return response}` and eventually log the cause.

Comment: @Antoniossss, That means Restoring the Interruption status is not required in the above case right? My understanding is also same. But Just wanted to double confirm.

Comment: I can only say that this is what I would do which may or may not be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program there you probably don't need to handle `InterruptedException` indeed.

But in a general case swallowing `InterruptedException` is a bad idea.
The main reason is that `Thread.interrupt()` (which causes `InterruptedException`) is the only way to interrupt many blocking operations provided by Java's standard library.

For instance, the proper handling of `InterruptedException` is typically required when we want to gracefully shutdown our application (i.e. when we want to close files, network connections and other resources before shutdown).

Some information about this can be found in [`Thread.interrupt()` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

Also I would recommend [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976527) and related chapters in "Java Concurrency In Practice", mentioned there.